# Jmeter with BI4.2 SP6 - Ajax request - 403 error

Tags: ajax, jmeter

while executing Ajax request in Jmeter script, it is failing with below error. please help me how to handle ajax request.

url/BOE/portal/${portal_id_g0}/InfoViewAppActions/ajaxUre/ajaxRequest

Sample Result:
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2019-11-27 14:33:18 GMT
Load time: 30
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 30
Size in bytes: 1683
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 404
Body size in bytes: 1279
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 403
Response message: HTTP/1.1 403

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
DataEncoding: ISO-8859-1

RESPONSE DATA:
HTTP Status 403 ? Forbiddenh1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}

## HTTP Status 403 ? Forbidden

**Type** Status Report

**Message** ???boetrustguard.TokenCreationFailed???[/BOE/portal/1908281108/InfoViewAppActions/ajaxUre/ajaxRequest] ???boetrustguard.TokenCreationFailedValue??? [MDAwRGxVXj8PLRGxgQTY0R29QVmRAMD01RDtMUlllNTAEQ] ???boetrustguard.TokenCreationFailedMessage???[???boetrustguard.token.missing???]

**Description** **The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.**

#### Apache Tomcat/8.5.13

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Dashboard SAP Analytics BI Load testing > Introduction to Apache JMeter > Additional considerations: Static vs. Dynamic Content](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Static+vs.+Dynamic+Content?original_fqdn=wiki.sdn.sap.com):

There is at least one dynamic parameter called **bttoken** which needs to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/):

1. Extracted from the previous response using a suitable JMeter's [PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
2. Recorded hard-coded value needs to be replaced with the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from step 1

Given you will be able to extract the **bttoken** and properly add it to your AJAX request it should start working normally.

Also be aware that AJAX requests have asynchronous parallel nature so if there is > 1 AJAX request in scope it's better to put them under [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) - this way you will get the same behaviour as the real browser.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Sorry delay in my response, was busy with other tasks. Tried as explained above but no luck and getting the same error. I am missing something here. could you please let me know how to add the bttoken to AJAX request ( already added the bttoken to earlier steps url ****/logon.faces). Please help.